# How can a public variable of a User control inside a FlipViewItem be set?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

I have a `FlipView` with custom `FlipViewItem`s inside that have close buttons - I am basically trying to handle those flipview buttons. The `FlipViewItem`s have a custom template called `DocumentFlipViewItemControlTemplate` which contains a custom `User Control` that has the close button inside it. The custom control has a collection of public variables (with getters and setters) that need to be set by the parent page - e.g. a reference to an instance of a page to close. How can those public variables be set?

The `FlipViewItem` template looks like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DocumentFlipViewItemControlTemplate" TargetType="FlipViewItem">
    <Grid Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="MainGrid">
        <MyProject:DocumentTabControl Name="MainDocumentTabControl"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700353.aspx) for your custom control public properties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PageProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Page", typeof(Page), typeof (ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public Page Page
{
    get { return (Page) GetValue(PageProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PageProperty, value); }
}
```

Now you can bind values to this property:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DocumentFlipViewItemControlTemplate" TargetType="FlipViewItem">
    <Grid Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="MainGrid">
        <MyProject:DocumentTabControl Name="MainDocumentTabControl" Page="{Binding ElementName=MyPageName}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

For the above to work you need to name your page:

```
<Page x:Name="MyPageName"
```

Comment: Thank you, I am marking this the answer however I feel it's too much of a struggle interacting with the contents of `FlipViewItem`s so I'm making my own component with a horizontally aligned stackpanel. Thanks.